# Ocultar origen de mensaje en inspector de navegadores

Tags: javascript

¿Hay alguna forma de ocultar la ruta que se muestra a la derecha de la consola de JS cuando se genera un mensaje?.

Me explico, por ejemplo, cuando generas un `console.log("");` te dice que lo generó la *Virtual Machine*, bueno, esa ruta aparece cuando yo genero mensajes en la consola y me indica que archivo y que línea lo generó.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay algunos mensajes que yo emito a la consola pero no quiero que se sepa donde se generó, es decir,  no me interesa que sepan donde se generó, solo que lo vean ya que es informativo.

Ejemplo de esto es por ejemplo cuando abres la consola en Facebook, aparece un mensaje pero no muestra la ruta que lo genera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo se puede hacer eso?

y tampoco el log que genera al ejecutar esta función:

```js
//Función que borra el log generado en la consola según el navegador
    function clearConsole() {
        if (typeof console._commandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {
            console.API = console._commandLineAPI;
        } else if (typeof console._inspectorCommandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {
            console.API = console._inspectorCommandLineAPI;
        } else if (typeof console.clear !== 'undefined') {
            console.API = console;
        }
        console.API.clear();
    }
```

Comment: Y cómo puedo hacer eso, donde hay documentación?, nunca lo he intentado

Comment: Te recomiendo que (_si has encontrado una solución a tu problema_), publica una nueva respuesta. Revisa: [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo así:

```
setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, 'Mesaje'));
```

Tenemos que:

- Usando [`fn.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind), obtienes una nueva función `fn` con parámetros pre-seteados.
- Usando [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout): ejecutamos una función.

Como la función `console.log` es código nativo, al usar `console.log.bind` generamos una función `console.log` con parámetros pre-seteado y con `setTimeout` podemos ejecutarla. De esta forma podemos lograr que no se imprima el "*origen*".

// Update

Para evitar que tu función `clearConsole` muestre el "*origen*", puedes hacerlo así:

```
function clearConsole() {
        if (typeof console._commandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {
            console.API = console._commandLineAPI;
        } else if (typeof console._inspectorCommandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {
            console.API = console._inspectorCommandLineAPI;
        } else if (typeof console.clear !== 'undefined') {
            console.API = console;
        }

        if (console.API) {
          setTimeout(console.API.clear.bind(console));
        }
    }
```

Comment: muchas gracias, eso seria todo :D